# Unexpected symbol in rstudio in decision tree

Tags: r, decision-tree

I am getting an unexpected symbol error in my code in R.

```
tree <- ctree(Income Level ~ Employment + Education Level + Profession,
              data = traindata)
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "tree<-ctree(Income Level"

The error code above is from the party packages.

Below is the error from the install.packages("tree")

```
modelRegTree <- tree(Income Level ~ Employment + Education Level + Profession + Sex, 
                     data = traindata)
```

> Error: unexpected symbol in "modelRegTree<-tree(Income Level"

I do not know what the unexpected symbol is as I am following along the work of a professor on yt but using my own data. Both times he uses this line of code and his works.

Comment: If your work isn't a trade secret, copyrighted or classified material, show us your script, together with R version and name and version of all the packages you're using.

Comment: R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)  
 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/tree_1.0-39.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 177743 bytes (173 KB)
downloaded 173 KB
 install.packages("party")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘TH.data’, ‘multcomp’, ‘mvtnorm’, ‘modeltools’, ‘strucchange’, ‘coin’, ‘zoo’, ‘sandwich’

Comment: library(tree)
> indie<-sample(2, nrow(Censusdata2), replace=TRUE, prob = c(0.66, 0.33))
> traindata<-Censusdata2[indie==1,]
> testdata<-Censusdata2[indie==2,]
> #above we just split the data into test & train and will now make a tree
> #above we just split the data into test & train and will now make dec tree model
> modelRegTree<-tree(Income Level~Employment+Education Level+Profession+Sex, data=traindata)
Error: unexpected symbol in "modelRegTree<-tree(Income Level"

Comment: Is "Income Level" the name for an identifier? I don't think in R spaces as part of these are legal. Can you refactor to replace the space with a dot, an underscore, or nothing?

Comment: Income Level  is the column name I assigned. I don't know how to make it an identifier, I will look it up on yt. But if i do make it an identifier with say, an underscore, the code should work then right? I'll test it out and reply back here. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I learned how to make it an identifier and i installed the proper packages as well. I will try this again very soon.

Comment: I did change the column name and make it the identifier. It did work after I did that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I made Income an identifier and changed the column heading to Income_Classification. Then my code worked. I also installed the correct packages, caret & tree, to make the tree print out.